# column-wise normalization (scaling) of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, normalization

I'd like to normalize (to put in range `[0, 1]`) a 2D array in python, but with respect to a particular column.

for example, given:

```
a = array([[1 2 3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

I need something like "norm_column_wise(a,1)" which takes matrix "a", and normalize only the second column [2,5,8],

the result should be:

```
norm_column_wise(a,1) = array([[1,0,3],[4,0.5,6],[7,1.0,9]])
```

I wrote a simple code for normalization:

```
def norm_column_wise(arr): 
    return (arr-arr.min(0))/(arr.max(0)-arr.min(0))
```

But it works for all columns of the array. How to modify this simple code in order to specify the particular column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with normalization here? I don't see why [2,5,8] would be normalized to [0,0.5,1.0], as given in your example.

Comment: @physicalattraction, thanks for this comment. This is a simple scaling from [a,b] -> [0,1]. it's done by (Z-min(Z))/(max(Z)-min(Z)).

Comment: In my case min = 2, max = 8, so ([2,5,8] - [2,2,2])/6 = [0,0.5,1.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use numpy for that.

```
import numpy as np

def normalize_column(A, col):
    A[:,col] = (A[:,col] - np.min(A[:,col])) / (np.max(A[:,col]) - np.min(A[:,col]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = np.matrix([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], dtype=float)
    normalize_column(A, 1)
    print (A)
```

Result

```
[[ 1.   0.   3. ]
 [ 4.   0.5  6. ]
 [ 7.   1.   9. ]]
```

Following the remark above, the max-min can be replaced with:

```
np.ptp(A,0)[0,col]
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Where is the previous answer? It disappeared. Another thing is, how to keep the original array ("A") unaffected? If I apply "normalize_column(A, col)" several times on the same array, it changes it every time.

Comment: Instead of `A[:,col] = ...`, make `B` as a copy of `A`, write `B = ...` with the exact same code on the dots, and return `B`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mean, make a copy and write `B[:,col] = ...`, not just `B = ...`.